# Creating a pipeline function that is asynchronous so functions can be awaited

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple pipeline function that takes in an object as an argument. The object is returned to the next function.

The functions themselves need to be awaited inside the `for of` loop. I've tried to find examples of how to do this and have read multiple articles without success. When I add `async` in front of the pipeline `function` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: pipeline(...) is not a function
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
async function pipeline(...funcs) {... // Throws the error

function pipeline(...funcs) {
  return function(val) {
    let lastResult
    for (let func of funcs) {
      console.log(func)
      lastResult = func(lastResult || val)
    }
    return lastResult
  }
}

const pipe = pipeline(
  function1,
  function2,
  function3
)(object)
```

Comment: In front of *which*  `function` keyword did you put the `async`?

Comment: have you tried turning pipeline into an async function?

Comment: I would recommend not to put `await` in the `pipeline`. Be explicit about promise-returning functions, and pass something like `p => p.then(function2)` instead of `function2`.

Comment: I added it in-front of the pipeline function. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @Bergi looking at your suggestion now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the pipeline must not be async but rather executing it:

```
function pipeline(...funcs) {
  return async function(val) {
    for (let func of funcs) {
      console.log(func);
      val = await func(val);
    }
    return val;
  } 
}
```

Comment: This solved it perfectly. Thank you. Will mark as correct in 8 minutes. :)